# $wpdb->get_results returns empty but value exists

Tags: wpdb, date

this is my first question here. More then 5 years working with Wordpress, I always find the right way through the Google, but in this case I did not even know what to do, I really stacked :( So ...

I have MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statsdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `min` float NOT NULL,
  `max` float NOT NULL,
  `avg` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=236 ;
```

When I am trying to get data with $wpdb like

```
SELECT * FROM statsdata WHERE `date` = '2015-04-28' AND `sid` = '2' LIMIT 1

    $sql_data = "SELECT * FROM " . $data_db_name . " WHERE `date` = '".$today."' AND `sid` = '".$sid."' LIMIT 1";   
    $data = $wpdb->get_results($sql_data);
```

I am getting empty result :( ... If I will make this query in phpmyadmin or directly from console it returns what I need ... Whats wrong here ?

P.S. Here is small peace of my data

```
INSERT INTO `statsdata` (`id`, `date`, `sid`, `pid`, `min`, `max`, `avg`) VALUES
(1, '2015-04-27', 2, 1, 200.401, 230.5, 229.451),
(2, '2015-04-27', 3, 1, 223, 235.61, 229.305),
(3, '2015-04-27', 1, 1, 232.027, 243.949, 237.988),
(4, '2015-04-28', 1, 1, 232.027, 243.949, 237.988),
(5, '2015-04-28', 2, 1, 232.027, 243.949, 237.988),
(6, '2015-04-28', 3, 1, 238.02, 243.506, 240.763)
```

Comment: Have you tried hard coding a MySQL string in your $wpdb-> get_results call instead of a string concatenated with vars? Would bet the MySQL string you create is malformed.

Comment: If clear read my question, I have wrote "If I am making this query SELECT * FROM statsdata WHERE `date` = '2015-04-28' AND `sid` = '2' LIMIT 1 directly in console I got right results"

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `SELECT * FROM statsdata LIMIT 1` just to be sure your table is accessible by WP?

Comment: I don't think @jrothafer is questioning the query but questioning whether your query is getting into you $sql_data variable properly

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say without hands on access to your data. Either the query is actually failing or the query is not something you expect in that context.

You should enable error reporting via `$wpdb->show_errors( true )` before it and check `$wpdb->last_query` for sanity after.

Comment: SQL in my prev comment is exactly what I am getting from $wpdb->last_query, did not try show_errors, but it seems no errors with it, it seems something with wpdb because, I am getting results directly in console.

Comment: This `$wpdb->show_errors( true )` is trully life-saving! I didn't knwo about that! :) Thanks! :)